# check if value exists in 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2d array in the format

```
emi_309 | present | weak   | 6
emi_310 | present | strong | 9
emi_319 | present | medium | 8
emi_315 | present | weak   | 5
```

I want to check if a value exists in the first column using a simple function

E.g, check if emi_77 exists in the first column

I came across `$.inArray(value, array)` but this function is for a 1d array only.

Is there something similar for 2d array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you do a combination of `$.inArray` and [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
if ($.inArray(value, $.map(arr, function(v) { return v[0]; })) > -1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `$.grep` to create new array and check it's length

```
var val='emi_77';
if( $.grep( twoDarray, function(item){ return item[0]===val; }).length){
  /* item exists*/
}
```

`$.grep` will not affect original array

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it simply, without Jquery.

```
for (var i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i][0] == 'emi_77'){
            alert("exists");
        }
}
```

If you wanna take this further, you can use the function below;

```
function IsIn2D(str,order,array){
  for (var i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
        return array[i][order] == str;
  }
}
```

where;
 *array* is the array you want to search
 *str* is the string you want to check if it exists
 *order* is the order of the string in the internal arrays
for example, by appling this to the question's sample 2D array:
emi_309 | present | weak   | 6
emi_310 | present | strong | 9
emi_319 | present | medium | 8
emi_315 | present | weak   | 5

```
IsIn2D('emi_77',0,array); /*returns false*/
IsIn2D('emi_315',0,array); /*returns true*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this methods to search from 2D array.
Just check with converting to string and compare.

```
function isArrayItemExists(array , item) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        if(JSON.stringify(array[i]) == JSON.stringify(item)){
            return true;
        }
            }
            return false;
}
```